# Capture value on page submit

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am a web developer, in my application I have a form and text box. If I type any text in the text box and when I submit the value it is not getting captured, but its taking the default value.

```
<form class="form-search" onsubmit="myfun();return false;" name="myFrm">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:225px" style="height:5px" placeholder="Enter your City OR Area..." value="jayanagar,bangalore" >
  <input type="submit" value="Search" class='btn btn-default'>
</form>

<script>
    myfun(){        
        window.location.reload();   
     }
 </script>
```

It should capture the textbox value before refreshing, and the captured data will be passed to the API as parameter. I am unable to capture data,
but in Firefox this is working as I expected. How can I do this?

Comment: Especially in chrome , on submit the page is refreshing without capturing the text box value..

Comment: Put here, what you have done so far....

Comment: <form class="form-search" onsubmit="myfun();return false;">
             
              <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:225px" style="height:5px" placeholder="Enter your City OR Area..."  value="jayanagar,bangalore" > <input type="submit" value="Search"  class='btn btn-default'>
               
                 
             </form>                                                          <script> myfun(){window.location.reload();}</script>

Comment: You have written page reload here so the page is refreshing.
What do you expect to do here?

Comment: and the captured data will be passed to the api as parameter...i am unable to capture data .... but in fire fox this is working as i am expected.

Comment: you mean, you have too pass data using the query string

Comment: You should provide the code on your question itself with the code that worked for you in Firefox as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Text box value can be easily captured..

```
<form class="form-search" onsubmit="myfun();return false;" name="myFrm">
     <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:225px" style="height:5px" placeholder="Enter your City OR Area..." value="jayanagar,bangalore" >
     <input type="submit" value="Search" class='btn btn-default'>
</form>
<script>
 function myfun(){          // this is the correct way of defining a function
    alert(document.myFrm.search.value);     
      /*
       You can do here what ever you want.
      */    
    window.location.reload();   
 }
 </script>
```

First thoroughly look for the other questions similar to your problem and then ask your question. You are not here just to make reputation.

Comment: hello sir,  please go through this link http://onze.in/dellosl_demodv2.htm   open this link in firefox do some search in the map place search box,   give indian area name to search. it will work .... but same thing do it in chrome its not working...please give me the usefull answers... thanks in advance.

Comment: For security reasons in the latest version of most modern browsers, http iframes no longer load in https pages by default.

However, several workarounds are available:
1. If possible, update the iframe URL to https
2. Map the site
3. Chrome users can change the behavior using the shield button. See help article.
Although not recommended, you can also use the command line flag---allow-running-insecure-content to prevent Chrome from checking for insecure content.

Comment: Instructions on how to add a command line flag can be found on Chromium site(http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

Comment: my pleasure, One more thing In stack network. You don't want your question to be down voted. Seriously neither I. If you find any answer useful and that worked for you. It's better to mark it accepted. It will improve your reputation.

Comment: even in my localhost  also , its not working . when i click sumit page is reloading , again its taking the default value of textbox... i need to capture the old text box value when it reloads.   do help me

Comment: Check your chrome console when u load in your page. There are several iframe errors and u'll get pretty useful information from there.